# Vuetify - TypeError: Vue.observable is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am having an issue installing vuetify in my Visual studio's 2019 project. I am using vuetify 2.3.4 with vuetify-loader 1.6. Vuetify appears to be working, being that I can see styles being presented on one of my v-btn tags. However the console is still showing the following error **"TypeError: Vue.observable is not a function"**. I have attempted a few google searches and haven't found anyone else that has posted about his issue. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some relevant code:

**Main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify' 

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.config.productionTip = true;

new Vue({
    vuetify,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

**vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

**Index.html**

```
    <v-app>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </v-app>
```

**component with button**

```
<template>
        <v-btn class="vbtn" small color="blue">Primary</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Button'
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**Image of Vuetified button:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you're using an older version of vue that doesn't have Vue.observable

Comment: @EricGuan that was right! thank you. Post an answer and I will happily give you your points!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using an older version of vue that doesn't have Vue.observable, which is available starting from `vue@2.6.0`

Comment: I'm using "vue": "^3.0.0-0" and getting the same error...? :(

Comment: Ah, in Vue3 it is no longer observable, but reactive - and so: import {reactive} from 'vue';

Answer (score -1):

the `Vue.observable` has been integrated from version 2.6.0 of vueJS https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable
it is therefore necessary to update the library with the following command

with npm : `npm update vue`

with yarn : `yarn upgrade --latest vue`